# How do I "roll back" to a previous version of my Workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have hosed my workflow somehow. Rather than continue to gut it in vain, I want to rollback to a previous version.  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: IN SPD 2013 its not working
Try with SPD 2010

Comment: SD2010 will not open SD2013 sites.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This blog](http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=173) explains how to use SharePoint Designer to restore a previous version of a workflow in detail.

Basically:

1. Go to the folder All Files in SharePoint designer (use SharePoint Designer 2010 if connecting with a SharePoint 2013 farm or you'll get a server busy error), when you have opened your site
2. Open Workflow folder
3. Locate your workflow and expand it (+)
4. For each file: Right click and click "Version history", select the correct version and click restore
5. Restart SharePoint designer
6. Open the version the normal way (not via All Files), and Publish