# Workflows Rolls Back to Previous Version After Migration

Tags: sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, 2016, migration, 2019

I just migrated to SharePoint 2019 from SharePoint 2016.  Issuses I am having is for another post. One issue that has been a deep thinker are my SharePoint 2010 workflows. The workflows keep sending many emails at one time time for the same list item. Then I see that the workflow rolled back to a previous version.

Why is this? How can I stop for the workflows sending many emails when this did not happen before the migration? How can I restore to most recent workflow so I don't have to modify all workflows to match latest before the migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For restore an earlier version of workflow, you can use SharePoint designer. Find your workflow with issues, and restore it to an earlier version.

1. Go to the folder All Files in SharePoint designer (use SharePoint
   Designer 2010 if connecting with a SharePoint 2013 farm or you'll
   get a server busy error), when you have opened your site
2. Open Workflow folder
3. Locate your workflow  For each file: Right click
   and click "Version history", select the correct version and click
   restore
4. Restart SharePoint designer Open the version the normal way (not via
   All Files), and Publish.

Reference：[How do I "roll back" to a previous version of my Workflow?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69459/how-do-i-roll-back-to-a-previous-version-of-my-workflow)