# How to restore to previous version of Workflow with SharePoint Designer 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have a workflow, that I was editing and due to Office 365 crash, I had to close SharePoint Designer 2013 and reopen. 
When reopened, I realize that the workflow got messed up with all condition removed.

Google save me this [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69459/how-do-i-roll-back-to-a-previous-version-of-my-workflow#:~:text=Open%20Workflow%20folder,Restart%20SharePoint%20designer) to restore to previous version from All files by:

1. Go to the folder All Files in SharePoint designer (use SharePoint Designer 2010 if connecting with a SharePoint 2013 farm or you'll get a server busy error), when you have opened your site
2. Open Workflow folder
3. Locate your workflow and expand it (+)
4. For each file: Right click and click "Version history", select the correct version and click restore
5. Restart SharePoint designer
6. Open the version the normal way (not via All Files), and Publish

The problem is step 3, I can't find any Workflow in the Workflow folder, except a folder named "Forms". Which has no item in it too.

How to find the workflow and restore it back to its original glory?
I have Owner access to the site and had previously worked on the said Workflow, edited and published it. But never tried to see its history before.

Any help here is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the below steps:

1. In the left pane of SharePoint Designer, click the little pin icon next to **All Files**.
2. Once All Files is expanded, scroll down and expand out your folder called **Workflows**. Note that if you have not actually created any workflows yet, you will not have this folder. Each workflow will be a “subfolder” under workflows. One weird little thing to point out also is that if you changed the name of any workflow after you created it, that new name will not show here, only the original name of each workflow will show in this list.
3. The workflow that I want to restore a previous version of is called “Check Audit Month”, so I’ll expand out that folder. Now I can see all of the files that my workflow is comprised of.
4. Each of these files has a set of versions. Right-click on the XOML file, and choose **Version History**. I want to get rid of all the changes I made today and revert back to the 4/12 version which I know worked correctly. I scroll down and click on the most recent 4/12 version. (I’ve blurred out the domain name I’m working in)
5. Click **Restore**.
6. Right-click on the next file, the XOML.rules. Go find that exact same date/time of the file as the one in the previous step, and **restore it**. Note that the version number may NOT be the same.
7. Right-click the next file, which is xoml.wfconfig.xml. Do the same thing by finding that same date/time that matches the one you restored at step 4. Restore it.
8. In this case, I don’t need to change anything about my InfoPath XSN file, which is the task form as part of the tasks that are assigned in the workflow. I’m skipping that one.
9. An important step after you’ve restored the old versions… **EXIT SharePoint Designer.** This is because of a cached version of your workflow needing to be refreshed.
10. **Re-open your site** in SharePoint Designer. When you open your workflow in the normal way now (as opposed to the funky way we did in step 2), you will see that good old version that you just restored.
11. Click **Publish**. Now your restored workflow is live and in use on the site.

**The above solution applies to**

This solution applies to all versions of SharePoint 2010, 2007, and **SharePoint Online with Office 365**. This does NOT apply to SharePoint 2013 workflows but DOES apply to SharePoint 2010 workflows created in SharePoint 2013.

Reference:

[SharePoint Designer – Restore Previous Workflow Version](https://www.google.com/amp/s/wonderlaura.com/2012/05/02/sharepoint-designer-restore-previous-workflow-version/amp/)

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I do see the "Workflow" folder, but it is empty. Do you know how do I view the list of Workflows in the folder?

Comment: Hi - I will check and update here.

Comment: Heard from Microsoft my company do not opt to store Workflow versions. So I cant restore from previous versions, all I can do is undo until last saved change. So the above solution will work for normal scenarios